# How do I convert an unsigned raster to a signed raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-conversion

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.  I need to convert two rasters from 8bit unsigned to an 8bit signed raster so I can do a subtraction and get both positive and negative values.

I've tried to use the [copy raster tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000094000000) that allows you to set the raster pixel type, but it always comes out the other side as an unsigned raster.

I tried converting my GRID to a .tiff, then using the copy command, but the Copy Raster tool will only output a GRID.  After converting and copying I still got an unsigned raster output.

[image]

Comment: some format do not support 8bit signed. have you checked this table ? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000000q000000#GUID-E7CE756B-C01C-49AC-8395-505AA0A4E8AE

Comment: @radouxju My input raster is a GRID, which supports 8 Bit signed integers.

Answer (score 2):

Esri GRIDs are either 32bit signed integer or floating point. You don't need to do anything before subtracting. Paraphrased from the same [help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000q000000#GUID-66C5A850-E338-41E6-AA9C-7D192B915590) 
@radouxju linked to:

```
Format     Description                   Supported data types 
Esri Grid  A proprietary Esri format     32-bit signed integer
           that supports 32-bit integer  32-bit floating point
           and 32-bit floating-point 
           raster grids.
```

The "[Bit depth capacity for supported export formats](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000q000000#GUID-E7CE756B-C01C-49AC-8395-505AA0A4E8AE)" table further down the page doesn't mean that GRIDs can be exported as 8 bit signed, it means that they have the bit depth capacity to store 8 bit signed data.

As to the [copy raster tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000094000000) only exporting GRIDs - it looks like you didn't add a '.tif' extension to your output path. The help states if you don't use an extension, the output will be a GRID.

Comment: Gahh I tried `.tiff` with an extra f. When I opened the layer properties it stated the raster was 8 Bit unsigned in GRID format.  Since I was subtracting 2006 impervious surface from the 2011 layer and there were no negative numbers am I to assume that there was no afforestation or other removed impervious surface?

Comment: You could also [download](http://www.mrlc.gov/nlcd11_data.php) the NLCD 2006 to 2011 Percent Developed Imperviousness Change (66MB) dataset

Comment: bingo! I'd only seen the 2001 to 2006 layer available.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The valid range of values for 8bit unsigned is 0 - 255.  The range for 8bit signed is -128 to 127.  If you have values larger than 127 in the input you will need to use 16bit signed.

Try the outputs as 16_BIT_SIGNED.  Set the scale_pixel_value to NONE.

Comment: I'm using NLCD percent impervious surface data which has a range of 0-100 integers only.

Comment: @Roy, What is the NoData value for your dataset?